# Insert pagination links - wp_link_pages() - before filters on posts

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages

I'm trying to add pagination support for some longer posts on my site. I've added the `wp_link_pages()` function to my single.php file, after `the_content`, but this causes the pagination links to display under some end-of-post plugins I have (YARPP and Better Author Bio, if that matters).

I'd like the pagination links to appear at the end of the actual content, before any filter hooks are added. How can I do this without editing the the `get_the_content` function in wp-includes/post-template.php? Do I need to write a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you have directly edited the single.php file, try to make a function and in it return `wp_link_pages()` and in add_action set a priority. Try this function

```
function pagination_after_post()
{
 return wp_link_pages();
}

add_action('the_content','pagination_after_post',1);
```

My WP PHP is not that good, my function might be wrong, this is just an example, but this way you can get pagination exactly after post

Comment: That makes sense. Let me play with that and then I'll throw you the big green check mark.

Comment: It worked, but now I'm having other issues. Opening a new question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @hookedonwinter your welcome

Comment: If you're interested.. here's the followup http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28526/wp-link-pages-output-appears-twice